# Multiple domains to single document root

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, domain

I am currently working on a distributed CMS that is built on a traditional LAMP stack. Customers can access their backend (and front end) using a subdomain of their username, for example:

`benm.mycms.com`

However, now we want to be able to add support custom domains, so that the user can decide to point any domain to their account, for example:

`benscms.com`

The site should be accessible from both URLs still, but we need multiple domains to point to the same document root on the server. I know that this can be achieved using Name-based virtual hosts in Apache, but we want an entirely automated process (so that when the customer fills in the form, it just happens). Is there a way around it without modifying the main Apache conf files?

Essentially what we're trying to achieve is that many domains access the same PHP system, but we detect the customer based on the domain used (or the subdomain, if that's their preferred route).

Comment: Why can’t the Apache conf files not be modified? What do you mean with the “main” ones? When you user adds the custom URL via a webform on your page and includes a new SSL cert, you could automate the creation/modification of her virtual host conf file.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have a single Apache virtual host without any domain name, and have that as the default virtual host on the server.

Then, in your PHP application you read the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable, which contains the `Host:` HTTP header.

Comment: Voted for this. But how would you tackle SSL?

Comment: Good point, one really cannot, unless one has a wildcard certificate for some domain. Or then some fancy system that adds a new SAN host entry to certificate whenever a new host is used.